# Chart.js data/label scale

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, label, chart.js

I want to create a linechart for a intern project at my company. On the yAxis I want orders. On the xAxis I want month( Jan - Dec). So there are 12 labels on the xAxis. My problem is that only the first 12 orders get picked from data:. How can I fix this ? The same problem is with a month. I put a link to illustrate in here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY993.jpg
And here is my code:

```
 <canvas id="orderChartCurrentMonth" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
  <%= foo = ((Date.today).beginning_of_month) %>
  var ctx = document.getElementById("orderChartCurrentMonth");
  var orderChartCurrentMonth = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [
        "<%=foo %>", "<%=foo + 1.week%>", "<%=foo + 2.week %>","<%=foo + 3.week%>", "<%=foo + 4.week%>"
      ], //x-Achse
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Graph Orders last week',
        data: <%= (foo..foo.end_of_month).map { |date| Company.graph_order(date).to_f}.inspect  %> //y-Achse
      }]},
    options:{
      legend:{
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 10
      }}]}}})
</script>
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an query that provides aggregate data grouped by month (or week). While you could do it with your database's date functions, I suggest using the Groupdate gem which will streamline the process in case you need it frequently. The you could do something like.

```
# this should probably be done in a controller action
<% @data = Order.where(date: 1.years.ago.beginning_of_month..Time.now).group_by_month(:date).count %>


# get an array of monthly labels in js file
...
labels: <%= @data.map{ |month, order_count| month } %>
...

# get the values for those months
...
data: <%= @data.map{ |month, order_count| order_count } %>
...
```

Needless to say, this example just shows a monthly order count. If you need other values you'd have to adjust the query. Furthermore Groupdate offers a lot of options to group this data. Be sure to read the docs: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate